# PHP - session not causing a redirect with header

Tags: php

I am trying to make  the user get redirected to the index.html page in case the $_SESSION['loggedin'] is already set. For some reason, it doesn't redirect the user, although the $_SESSION['loggedin'] when echoed returns a value.

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['loggedin'])) { header('Location: index.html');};
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you get a warning error? If you try to header redirect after anything has been printed to the screen it will fail.

Comment: Are you sure `session_start()` isn't missing and `$_SESSION['loggedin']` has a value, that does not return false when checked with [empty()](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)?

Comment: session_start() is right on top of the page, before any HTML. The line of code from the original post is right under the session_start(). When I echo $_SESSION['loggedin'] it returns a value that is set in the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`header('Location: index.html');` sets an http header which needs to be set before any content is sent, i.e. before any echo. Also you should terminate your script after you set the location header.

Comment: I added exit; after the header redirect and it worked. I guess the script continued to run and it caused some other redirects to trigger which are below that code. Thanks!